# 3D transform effect not working in Firefox and in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css, 3d, cross-browser

I am trying to do a box transition effect, which work well in the Chrome.

But the transform property is not working in Firefox and in Internet Explorer.
There is the problem in the figure: hover and figcaption CSS .
But I don't have any idea how to change it ...
the figcaption CSS

```
figcaption {
    webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    /* these two lines aren't not working in Firefox and Internet Explorer */
}
```

Any idea to overcome this issue?

My full CSS:

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1.5em;
    width: 45em;
}
figure {
    float: left;
    height: 6em;
    margin: 1.5em;
    width: 12em;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(500) rotateX(90deg) 
    translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
    -moz-transform: perspective(500) rotateX(90deg) 
    translateY(-3em) translateZ(3em);
    transform: perspective(500px) rotateX(90deg) translate3d(13px,0,13px);
}
img {
    background-color: #222;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover img {
    box-shadow: none;
}
figcaption {
    background-color:;
    color:black;
    padding: 1.5em;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 15px -10px hsla(0,0%,0%,.25);
    border-radius:10px;
}
h3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:300px;padding-top:195px;">
<figure>
   <img src="images.jpg" style="border-radius:10px;" width="190px"  alt="Portfolio Item">
   <a style="text-decoration:none;"href="http://www.tamilvu.org/">
    <figcaption style="background-color:#FAFAD2;">
  <!--      <h3></h3>   -->
       <h3 style="text-color:black">USING .NET<h3>
    </figcaption>
 </a>
</figure>

<figure>
     <img src="images.jpg" width="190px"  alt="Portfolio Item">
   <a style="text-decoration:none;"href="http://www.tamilvu.org/">
    <figcaption style="background-color:#6E8ECF">
        <h3></h3>
        <p style="color:">OPEN SOURCE</p>
    </figcaption>
 </a>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="images.jpg" width="190px"  alt="Portfolio Item">
  <a style="text-decoration:none;"href="http://www.tamilvu.org/">
    <figcaption style="background-color:#EE82EE;height:42px;">
       
        <p>MOBILE APPLICATION</p>
    </figcaption>
 </a>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the trasition property only with perfixes , add the trasition property without the prefix, like so:

```
figure {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s; // add this line.
}
```

You should now see your transition work in IE too. Also do you really need `translate3d(13px,0,13px)` ? you can take that off.

Comment: .thanks for your response...i tried your idea....but there is  no changes in the firefox and IE.